# is it possible to add a hyperlink to sharepoint document which will be opened from browser in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, pdf, sharepoint, hololens

Is it possible to add a hyperlink to Sharepoint document which should be opened from browser in **Unity**?
So that i can scroll my **pdf** documents by wearing **HoloLens** or Realwear devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unity's [Application.OpenURL](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.OpenURL.html).

> Opens the URL specified, subject to the permissions and limitations of your app’s current platform and environment. This is handled in different ways depending on the nature of the URL, and with different security restrictions, depending on the runtime platform.
>
> *Note: This method can be used to open more than just web pages, so it has important security implications you must be aware of.*